# How to make node_module folder created by docker container sync with local?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file like this

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  node:
    container_name: node
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - $NODE_PORT:3000
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    command: npm run start:dev

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - $MONGO_PORT:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
volumes:
  mongodb:
```

At line `- /app/node_modules`,  I need to do this to make sure node_modules folder be ignored when building the image. It works right, but because node_modules folder in docker container does not sync with local, so in local machine, this folder is empty, and IDE show error because can't solve dependency. So, can you tell me how to make This folder sync with local ?

Comment: You can add .dockerignore [just like .gitignore] file at the root of the project so that it is ignored in the build context and not used while building the image. In this way you have a dependencies locally and on every build it reuses the cache (if not changed).

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `and IDE show error because can't solve dependency` if you try to run it locally outside of the container?  Or while editing code in the editor?

Comment: I'd recommend using Node on your host environment for day-to-day development; you can run `docker-compose up mongo`, and configure the application to point at `http://localhost:$MONGO_PORT` (filling in an actual port).  Then when you go to deploy this application, you can delete the `volumes:` and use the code built into the Docker image, without trying to manage volumes' lifecycle.